# processing an array via method

Tags: java

is it possible to use a reference and pass it to a method as a argument and do the
initialization in the method body in java?
what i mean is this:
i have a method that get's a array as parameters:

```
public static void arrayreader(int [] [] m){
int rows,cols;
rows=input.nextInt();cols=input.nextInt();
m = new int [rows][cols];
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
       m[i][j] = input.nextInt();
       }
   }
}
```

i want to do the initialization of array in the method body not in the main method
but java dont allow that and says it's not initialized

Comment: No, you cannot do that, all variables should be initialized before using it

Comment: @PradeepSimha all local variables  and final  should be initialized before using them , not instance vars

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR..yes, but I think OP hasn't mentioned in question. Thanks.. :)

Comment: No you cannot do that. Because Java dosent know you are initializing in your passing method or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because when you say:

```
m = new int [rows][cols];
```

You are effectively assigning a new array to "m" reference(pointer), thus you are losing the reference to the array passed as argument.

Comment: tnx but why this happening?u mean java will generate 2 reference's that the first one will be garbage collected and the 2nd one will be used?

Comment: Do you understand the notion of pointer (like in C language)? If so, "m" is a pointer. In main() you point m to a memory zone containing an array, but then in arrayreader() you point it to a new zone containing a new array. Thus, what you say it's true, the first array will be garbage collected if no one else "points" at it (if you, for example, have assigned it to a variable in main() it won't be garbage collected)

Comment: Also: parameters in Java are always passed by-value. When you pass a reference to an object (an array is also an object) you pass the reference by-value. That means, that if you assign something to the parameter, you are not reassigning the reference object, but the reference itself: you are pointing the reference to a new object inside the method, but that does not affect the outside-of-the-method world.

Comment: You could then mark the answer as the solution if you feel it is the valid one.

Answer (score 3):

If you made that array a return value instead of a parameter, your main method can look like this:

```
int[][] m = arrayreader();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to initialise an array in the method, than there is no need to pass it as a parameter

you can do something like this instead

```
public static int[][] arrayreader()
{
   int rows,cols;
   int[][] result = new int[rows][cols];

   rows=input.nextInt();
   cols=input.nextInt();

   for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
       {
           result[i][j] = input.nextInt();
       }
   }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: What is `m` in `m[i][j]`? And you forgot to return the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can also create the array object in main like:

```
int rows,cols;
rows=input.nextInt();cols=input.nextInt();
m = new int [rows][cols];
```

and then can have the function like:

```
public static void arrayreader(int [] [] m, int rows, int cols){
 for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){
      m[i][j] = input.nextInt();
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't pass an int as a reference, it uses values instead. I don't think your code is going to work... Unless you remove the "m" parameter from the second method and make the 1st initialisation of "m" as global

Comment: did you try the similar code (as I mention)? It'll work as we are just assigning the values to the same array object

Comment: then you don't need to pass it as a parameter

Comment: if both (main and this function) are not in the same class, we may need to pass it

Comment: or if array is declared in the main method, we do need to pass it

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that I spent one day due to errors like:

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException`
  `at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)`

I implemented all the ideas from above in the code bellow which works like a charm for matrix multiplication:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MatmultC
{
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int a[][] = new int[m][n];
    arrayreader(a,m,n);
    printMatrix(a);

    int[][] b = readMatrix();
    printMatrix(b);

    int[][] c=mult(a,b);
    printMatrix(c);

  }

   public static void arrayreader(int [][] m, int rows, int cols) {
       for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
              m[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
           }
       }
   }


   public static int[][] readMatrix() {
       int rows = sc.nextInt();
       int cols = sc.nextInt();
       int[][] result = new int[rows][cols];
       for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
              result[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
           }
       }
       return result;
   }


  public static void printMatrix(int[][] mat) {
  System.out.println("Matrix["+mat.length+"]["+mat[0].length+"]");
       int rows = mat.length;
       int columns = mat[0].length;
       for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
               System.out.printf("%4d " , mat[i][j]);
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
       System.out.println();
   }

   public static int[][] mult(int a[][], int b[][]){//a[m][n], b[n][p]
   if(a.length == 0) return new int[0][0];
   if(a[0].length != b.length) return null; //invalid dims

   int n = a[0].length;
   int m = a.length;
   int p = b[0].length;

   int ans[][] = new int[m][p];

   for(int i = 0;i < m;i++){
      for(int j = 0;j < p;j++){
         for(int k = 0;k < n;k++){
            ans[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
         }
      }
   }
   return ans;
   }

}
```

where as input matrix we have inC.txt

```
4 3
1 2 3
-2 0 2
1 0 1
-1 2 -3 
3 2
-1 3
-2 2
2 1
```

in unix like cmmd line execute the command:

`$ java MatmultC < inC.txt > outC.txt`

and you get the output

outC.txt

```
Matrix[4][3]
   1    2    3 
  -2    0    2 
   1    0    1 
  -1    2   -3 

Matrix[3][2]
  -1    3 
  -2    2 
   2    1 

Matrix[4][2]
   1   10 
   6   -4 
   1    4 
  -9   -2
```